# Go back from pushed navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, master-detail

Screenshot below is of a sample xCode Master Detail project. I put a Delete button on the Detail scene's navigation bar. 
[image: Master-Detail Storyboard]

When I tap this button, I want the Detail view to close and go back to the Master view. This is the code:

```
-(IBAction)delete:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

It does not work. The default back button on the navigation bar does.  How do you close a view that has been pushed from accessory action?

Note, the above storyboard comes with the Master-Detail Application template:

[image: Master-Detail Application]

Comment: David why u dont embed split View Controller in navigation Controller instead of embedding the controllers (upper one and bottom )separately ???

Comment: The above is the Master-Detail template from xcode. No change was made by me except to add the "delete" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get back to the root by calling

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In your case, the problem is that you are pushing second navigation controller onto the navigation stack and it looks like this:

navigation controller -> table view controller -> navigation controller -> detail view controller

You should directly segue from the table view to the detail view so the navigation stack looks like:

navigation controller -> table view controller -> detail view controller